# Vue - Updating router-link query path with object that gets localstorage

Tags: javascript, vue.js, routes, local-storage, vue-router

I'm trying to get the value from my localstorage to pass into an object which I'm then passing into a router-link query.  I can get it to work on page load, **but the object won't update when the localstorage changes**.  Am I making this too complicated?

```
<router-link :to="{ path: '/trade', query: tradeQuery}" active-class="active" id="btn-trade">Trade</router-link>

computed: {
    tradeQuery() {
        const params = {
            mode: localStorage.getItem('tradeMode') || 'advanced',
            instrument: 'currentTrade',
        };
        return params;
    },
},
```

Comment: The problem with your computed property is that it is not reactive (does not reference any `data` or `prop` values). What updates your `localStorage` "tradeMode" value?

Comment: I have a button that switches it, it fires a function that sets the new local storage value.  I can use this function as an onclick even in this case I suppose, but I would much rather update the link

Comment: Can you show the code for this button click handler? Is it in the same component as your code above?

Comment: If you are using **vuex**, you could load the `localStorage` value into the vuex store on page load so you have the default value. And update `localStorage` value when you are doing mutations.